# How do I get the result from a MySQL DATEDIFF query as a variable to pass to a PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, datediff

I am trying to get the difference in seconds between the date/time in the column 'last_visited' in my table 'users' and the current date/time for a particular user.  I think the following query should do it:

```
$query ="SELECT unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(last_visit) from users WHERE username='$user'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

However, I am not sure how to get the result from this as a variable so that I can pass it to a PHP function.  Could someone help with this?

Comment: have you looked at the `$result`variable using `var_dump` ? Also, please don't use the `mysql_*` methods, there deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the result with a name:

```
$query ="SELECT unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(last_visit) AS time_diff from users WHERE username='$user'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
 $diff= $row['time_diff']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query ="SELECT unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(last_visit) AS time_difference from users WHERE username='$user'";
                                                                   ^
```

I guess it will be easier to use this variable if it has a proper name.

Comment: Thanks. How do I then pass 'time_difference' to my 'time_since' function as in `$visited = time_since (*SECONDS NEED TO GO HERE*);`

Comment: **c 2**'s comment above tells how to read data from the query result.

Comment: @Tim: Always link. What's above or below varies, because this site sometimes prefers your answer first, than the other. And welcome to SO!